# Mono, NTLM and empty Domains

Tags: c#, mono, ntlm

I'm using Mono 2.6.7 - if I don't specify a Domain the requested Host is taken for the NTLM Authentication - which leads to an unsuccessful login.

1 - Working: Login with Username 'domainXYZ/User123' -> Wireshark Capture of NTLM Packages:

```
Domain name: domainXYZ
User name: User123
```

2 - Working: Login with Username 'User123' on URL http://1.2.3.4/a.txt -> **.Net/Windows**:

```
Domain name: NULL
User name: User123
```

3 - Not Working: Login with Username 'User123' on URL http://1.2.3.4/a.txt -> **Mono/Debian**:

```
Domain name: 1.2.3.4
User name: User123
```

This authentication request is not working, because there is no Domain called 1.2.3.4 on the target machine.

My code for authentication without Domain information:

```
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(request.Username, request.Password);
// credential = new NetworkCredential(request.Username, request.Password, null); also not working
CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache { { new Uri(request.Url), "NTLM", credential } };
webClient.Credentials = credentialCache;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We were able to do a "simple" workaround to solve the domain issue. In general, we implemented the connection as a "fat" static library in Objective-C, using the ASIHTTPRequest framework for simplicity, did the API binding as described [here](http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types), and with some help from [here](http://iwayneo.blogspot.com/2010/04/three20-with-monotouch.html), we were able to include the created .dll and .a file into MonoDevelop and link against the needed frameworks.

Feel free to contact me, if you're interested in the source files.
I also have some more interesting links that helped us, but I need some more reputation to post them. Also, feel free to ask me for them.

Regards,
Andreas

Edit: Sorry, the most important information was missing. Setting the domain in ASIHTTPRequest to an empty string `[asiRequest setDomain:@""];` and wrapping the whole request in the static library did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed this problem in the Mono master and mono-2-10 branches: https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/214741630f96ddd3e847ff4050182674fe2d1602